# Grouping Python List of Objects

Tags: python, group-by, grouping

I have a list of Python Objects of type class Service. I would like to group this list according to one of the data members of this class

```
class service:
    def __init__(self, tasknum, candidatenum, features, cost):
        self.tasknum = tasknum
        self.candidatenum = candidatenum
        self.features = features
        self.cost = cost

s11 = service(1,1, features = [1], cost = 30)
s12 = service(1,2, features = [1], cost = 50)
s13 = service(1,3, features = [1], cost = 70)
s14 = service(1,4, features = [1], cost = 200)
s15 = service(1,5, features = [2], cost = 20)

lstservice = []
lst.append(s11)
lst.append(s12)
lst.append(s13)
lst.append(s14)
lst.append(s15)
```

I would like to group this list `lst` by the list features, that is, in the above, s11, s12, s13 and s14 would form one group. The grouping would be carried out on the list features such that in one group all the objects have the exact same value of features, that is, the list features is the same for all the objects in the group. How do I carry this out?

Comment: Are you looking for [itertools.groupby()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)?

Comment: If s1 has features 1 & 2, s2 has features 2 & 3, and s3 has features 1 & 3, what would the groups be?

Comment: You don't need ML for exact-match grouping.

Comment: @ScottHunter There would be three groups and they would all be in three different groups

Comment: @kauray: Care to explain *why* you end up with those groups?

Comment: @ScottHunter Because they all have different features. I want to find groups having the same features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scikit learn or a fuzzy cluster algorithm is very much overkill here where you have a definitive list that you want to group by.

You can create a dictionary that stores the features as keys and the list of services as values.  Note that since lists are mutable you will need to turn them to tuples before using them as keys ( or just always use tuples since features don't seem mutable ).

```py
from collections import defaultdict
grps = defaultdict(list)
for x in lst:
    grps[tuple(x.features)].append(x)
```